# Why is there a comma between a preposition and its complement?

Tags: commas

> Quirrell rolled off him, his face blistering, too, and then Harry
>   knew: Quirrell couldn’t touch his bare skin, not without suffering
>   terrible pain — his only chance was to keep hold of Quirrell, keep him
>   in enough pain to stop him from doing a curse. 
>  Harry jumped to
>   his feet, caught Quirrell by the arm, and hung on as tight as he
>   could. Quirrell screamed and tried to throw Harry off — the pain in
>   Harry’s head was building — he couldn’t see — he could only hear
>   Quirrell’s terrible shrieks and Voldemort’s **yells of, “KILL HIM!
>   KILL HIM!”** and other voices, maybe in Harry’s own head, crying,
>   “Harry! Harry!” (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

While reading the phrase I fumbled a second for looking for where the complement ‘of’ is. It seems that “KILL HIM! KILL HIM!” is the complement of ‘of’. Then why is there a comma between the two?

Comment: It's not there in my UK edition.  Here's what my copy says: Quirrell screamed and tried to throw Harry off – the pain in Harry's head was building – he couldn't see – he could only hear Quirrell's terrible shrieks and Voldemort's yells of ‘KILL HIM! KILL HIM!’ and other voices, maybe in Harry's own head, crying, ‘Harry! Harry!’

Comment: This is an instance of mechanical punctuation. See the Comments and Answer [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/8242/32).