# The usage of comma and period mark

Tags: sentence-construction, punctuation, commas, periods

I have read a sentence which made me confused:

> But Mary suddenly laughed, "How could that be?" she said. "It's only 2008 this year."

I wonder whether I can replace the first comma with a period because I think the sentence should be:

> But Mary suddenly laughed.  "How could that be?" she said. "It's only 2008 this year."

Comment: Both ways are correct. Personally, I prefer to use a coma there, but using a period instead is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the period instead of the comma.

I could understand the following sentence as saying that Mary laughed while saying what quoted.

> But Mary suddenly laughed, "How could that be?"

In  that case, the comma before the quote would be considered optional from somebody. (See [Should I always use a comma before a quote?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8242/should-i-always-use-a-comma-before-a-quote))

Since the quote is followed by "she said," that is an example of [comma splice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice).

> She smiled, she told me "I will see you later."

In the sentence shown in the question, replacing the comma with "and said" would be acceptable.

> But Mary suddenly laughed and said "How could that be?"

Replacing the comma with the period is also another solution.

> But Mary suddenly laughed. "How could that be?" she said, "It's only 2008 this year."

Comment: I think the last sentence in your answer should be: But Mary suddenly laughed. "How could that be?" she said."It's only 2008 this year" or But Mary suddenly laughed. "How could that be?"she said, "it's only 2008 this year."

Comment: _The great general George S. Patton once said, "No, no—the war is this way, you idiots!"_